# Program not producing Midi sound

Tags: java, midi

I've been reading Head First Java and this is the code  to practice making a sequencer and playing midi. Thing is I don't hear anything I searched through posts and I heard about a soundbank.gm file which I got and placed still nothing. Can't tell if it is my code or my PC as the book hasn't reached the point of explaining what all this does.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
public class MiniMiniMusicApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MiniMiniMusicApp  mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();
    }

    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer(); //get a sequencer
            player.open(); //open it
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack(); //ask the sequence for a track;
            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage(); //Put some midi events into the Track.
            b.setMessage(128,1,44,100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
            track.add(noteOff);
            player.setSequence(seq); //give the Sequence to the sequencer
            player.start(); // press play.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            player.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a note_on. For example:

```
ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage(); 
b.setMessage(144, 0, 60, 127);
MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(b, 2);
track.add(noteOn);

// Here's your note_off
ShortMessage b1 = new ShortMessage(); 
b1.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b1, 16);
track.add(noteOff);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on where I would put this noteOn if its before or after noteOff? EDIT never mind i got it working